# Wireless synchronisation program

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, wifi

hi I have been looking for help with not much luck till i arrived here.
 I want to develop an SQL server database and an application which will act as a server to allow a pda to send data to and wirelessly synchronise and information to sendAs it uses mobile application I would like to utilise it over a WIFI  network.Any information would be very apreciated. I will be using visual studio to develop as it has SQL SERVER  in built.
Thanks

Verma

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQLCE on the PDA there are two technologies that could help.

[SQL Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329.aspx)

[ADO.NET Synchronisation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Sync Framework v2.0 CTP1 is fairly new (Oct '08 release from MS) You can get more information about it, and the latest releases from the [Microsoft Sync Framework page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx).

> "Microsoft Sync Framework is a
>   comprehensive synchronization platform
>   that enables collaboration and offline
>   access for applications, services and
>   devices. It features technologies and
>   tools that enable roaming, sharing,
>   and taking data offline. Using
>   Microsoft Sync Framework, developers
>   can build sync ecosystems that
>   integrate any application, with any
>   data from any store using any protocol
>   over any network."